# Error while creating Work Item in Azure Devops using Rest API

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, azure-devops

I am getting below error when I am trying to create a Work Item in Azure Devops using the Rest API.

This is the PowerShell script I am using

```
$body ='[{"op": "add", "path": "/fields/System.Title", "from": null, "value": "Initiative Code"}]' | ConvertTo-Json
$body  = $body | ConvertFrom-Json
$supportAreaUri = 'https://MyOrganization.visualstudio.com/TestTeam1/_apis/wit/workitems/$Initiative?api-version=6.0'
$supportAreaUri = [uri]::EscapeUriString($supportAreaUri) 
$supportArea = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $supportAreaUri -Headers $Header -ContentType application/json -Body $body
```

I am getting this error when running the code:

> "$id": "1",
> "innerException": null,
> "message": "The request indicated a Content-Type of "application/json" for method type "POST" which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are: application/json-patch+json.",
> "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssRequestContentTypeNotSupportedException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi",
> "typeKey": "VssRequestContentTypeNotSupportedException",
> "errorCode": 0,
> "eventId": 3000

I am getting same error when I try in Postman as `Post` request.

Comment: Did you look closely at the error message and the documentation try adjusting your code accordingly? *Valid content types for this method are: application/json-patch+json.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the error message, appears like you are passing the Content Type : "application/json"

You will have to pass the Content Type header as `application/json-patch+json`

The corrected command would be

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $supportAreaUri -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $body
```

[image]

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Satya V and Daniel.

Postman result:

[image]

Power shell script

```
$connectionToken="{PAT}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$Url = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/wit/workitems/"+"$"+"{Work item type}?api-version=6.0"  
$Body = @"
[
 {
 "op": "add",
 "path": "/fields/System.Title",
 "from": null,
 "value": "Sample Bug Test"
 }
]
"@
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $Body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST
write-host $Result.id
```

Result:

[image]